# Oracle SQL Find A String & Work Backwards

Tags: sql, oracle

What I would like to do, is to locate a particular string within a result and then work backwards from that string to obtain what I need. So as an example, let's say I have a result of "This thing is heavy at 500KG no matter what". I want to find "KG" and then work backwards to obtain the "500KG".

The reason I want to work backwards from KG is that the results can have varying strings like "This thing is heavy at 500 kg" or "500 - This thing is heavy 500Kg" etc. The only constant is the KG (even in it's varying state).

I'm using regexp_instr and substr to narrow the result down to something like "This thing is heavy at 500KG" - essentially finding KG and removing everything after it.

Suggestions?

Comment: if I was you, I'd strip the kg from the end of the interim string and then regexp_substr to find digits at the end of the string. You might need to include full-stops and commas as well, depending on your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle's regular expression engine does not currently support look-aheads or look-behinds, so the process of finding the correct string that you describe in your question is not possible.

Having said that, you can just use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303) to do this; something like the following would probably work (depending on your data):

```
regexp_substr(str, '\d+\s?kg', 1, 1, 'i')
```

This searches for any number of digits, followed by an optional space, followed by the string `kg`. The other parameters are the position (start at 1), the occurrence (the first) and the match parameter (case insensitive).

This gets you what you want:

```
SQL> with str (s) as (
  2  select 'This thing is heavy at 500 kg'
  3    from dual
  4   union all
  5  select '500 - This thing is heavy 500Kg'
  6    from dual
  7         )
  8  select regexp_substr(s, '\d+\s?kg', 1, 1, 'i')
  9    from str;

REGEXP_SUBSTR(S,'\D+\S?KG',1,1,'I')
---------------------------------------------------
500 kg
500Kg

SQL>
```

This works because you're searching for a number *followed* by `kg`. So, if a number is not followed by this string then it won't be returned.

Depending on your data, and your desired output this may not be quite enough. For instance if kilograms can be represented as `k.g.` as well and you want to remove the space between the number and upper case the string you might want to do something like this:

```
SQL> with str (s) as (
  2  select 'This thing is heavy at 6872 kg'
  3    from dual
  4   union all
  5  select '157 - This thing is heavy 248K.g'
  6    from dual
  7         )
  8  select regexp_substr(s, '(\d+)\s?k\.?g', 1, 1, 'i', 1) || 'KG'
  9    from str;

REGEXP_SUBSTR(S,'(\D+)\S?K\.?G',1,1,'I',1)||'KG'
-------------------------------------------------------------------
6872KG
248KG

SQL>
```

The last parameter I've added is the sub-expression to be returned, identified by the group `(\d+)`. This picks out the first (only) sub-expression, which will be your number and concatenates the string `KG` to the end of that number.

Comment: IIRC, that last parameter is "new" in Oracle 11g. But you could get the same effect in 10g by using `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

Comment: The answer Ben has supplied is by far one of the best answers I've received on here in a long time. It's brief, concise, and to the point, with an explanation to what's going on. Bravo Ben!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle 10g, you can do the following (@Ben's answer works just fine in 11g or 12c):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mystring, '^.*?(\d+)\s*k\.?g.*$', '\1KG', 1, 1, 'i')
  FROM mytable
```

The reason we can't use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` here is that the final parameter (`subexpression`) does not exist in the 10g version of this function.

If you want to capture various units of measurement, that might be more difficult, but still not impossible, e.g:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mystring, '^.*?(\d+)\s*(k?g|lbs?|oz).*$', '\1\2', 1, 1, 'i')
  FROM mytable
```

This would capture grams (`g`), kilograms (`kg`), pounds (`lb` or `lbs`) and ounces (`oz`).